# Coverting an Int array on to a raster Java

Tags: java, arrays, int, bufferedimage, raster

This day i was watching [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPSJnzA0nLY) tutorial and he used this line...

```
private int[] pixels =((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer().getData());
```

But by some reason for him it works but for me it doesn't, i always get these two errors...

- Type mismatch: cannot convert from `DataBufferInt` to 
   `int[]`
- The method `getData()` is undefined for the type 
   `DataBuffer`

Help me pls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this often. Pay attention to the parentheses:

```
private int[] pixels =((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```